# Set values from 0 to n in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I set all values in `OrderNumber` column from *1* to *n*(when they are ordered by primary key) where *n* is entries count in table?

**EDIT:**

Let's assume we have 3 entries with ID's 4,7 and 15 ... I want to set their OrderValues 1,2 and 3.
I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This is a confusing word problem. Can you please show a small set of sample data, desired result after the update, and indicate the version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: I don't think this question desired be downvoted.

Comment: google has a lot of links like this: amsudeenb.blogspot.com.ar/2008/09/how-to-generate-rownum-in-sql-server. and this http://sqlserverplanet.com/oracleequivalents/rownum-in-sql-server. Unless you are looking for something else...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT ID, OrderValues, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
   FROM dbo.tablename
)
UPDATE x SET OrderValues = rn;
```

However, why on earth do you want to do this, when you can derive this information using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function at query time? Storing the values means that they are guaranteed to be out of date and out of sync the moment you insert/update/delete a single row in the table. So unless you plan to run this update after every DML operation (e.g. using a trigger), which isn't very logical to me, you're likely much better off getting these row_number values when you run the query vs. storing them in the table.

Comment: Thanks for solution. The reason to do that is to have ability to change ordering in that table from external program. I will run this query only one time to fill that column, after that all operation will be done by the help of that external program :)

Comment: Yes, it's seems little unnatural, but program logic wants to have values from 1 to n. With the help of that program user will be able to change order of values and after that it will not depend on ID values. It's like first time running script )))

Comment: I've tried this solution and I receive the error message: "ERROR:  column "rn" does not exist". How do I fix this?

Comment: @AndikanOtung Can you create a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org) where this fails? [Seems to work for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=505b20619a56b452644092b1f1fac6ff), you might use that example to spot any differences in the query you're trying to run (or maybe you are not using Microsoft SQL Server).

Comment: Ah, that's right. I'm using Postgres. I'll do more research then ask how this solution can be done in Postgres, if need be. 